# Understanding the proof of $\left ( A' \right )^{-1}=\left ( A^{-1} \right )^{'}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

Assume that $A$ is an $n \times n$ square matrix and is *nonsingular*.

To prove that $\left ( A' \right )^{-1}=\left ( A^{-1} \right )^{'}$, it is mentioned in the solution of the lecture notes that $$A'\left ( A^{-1} \right )^{'}=\left ( A^{-1} \right )^{'}A'=I.$$

This is the part that I don't understand. How does showing the above help us prove that $\left ( A' \right )^{-1}=\left ( A^{-1} \right )^{'}$?

Comment: What does the $'$ in $A'$ stand for? Transposition?

Comment: Uniqueness of inverse.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri $A'$ is the transpose of matrix $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a matrix $N$ and you find that $MN = NM = I$ then this automatically implies that $M$ is the unique inverse to your matrix $N$. We denote this by $N^{-1} = M$.

So if you show that $A' \left(A^{-1}\right)' =\left(A^{-1}\right)'A' = I$ then you've shown that $\left(A^{-1}\right)'$ is the inverse to $A'$. But we denote the inverse to $A'$ as $\left(A'\right)^{-1}$. So this means that $\left(A'\right)^{-1} = \left(A^{-1}\right)'$.

---

If you still can't quite see it, try giving $A'$ a new name; like so. Let $N = A'$ and $M = (A^{-1})'$. Then you've showed $NM= MN = I$. So this means $N^{-1} = M$. That is $(A')^{-1} = M = (A^{-1})'$.

Comment: Still not seeing it quite yet, but if $A' = N$ then is $\left ( A' \right )^{-1} = N^{-1} = M$? I'm trying it with new labels,

Comment: Right. Let $N = A'$ and $M = (A^{-1})'$ Then you've showed $NM= MN = I$. So this means $N^{-1} = M$. That is $(A')^{-1} = M = (A^{-1})'$.

Comment: Ah I can see it now. Quite a sneaky trick!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that if $Y$ satifies $XY=YX=I$, then $Y=X^{-1}$ (by uniqueness, as pointed out by Zain Patel). In this case we have $X=A'$ and $Y={(A^{-1})}'$, therefore ${(A^{-1})}'=X^{-1}={(A')}^{-1}$.